# Setting two TikZ images to be at the same height on a line

Tags: tikz-pgf, align, vertical-alignment, center

I have two TikZ images (one is citcuitikz) and they are on the same line, and centred with \centering. The issue is that they are not quite at the same height, as the circuitikz is slightly less high. I would like to find a way to centre the circuitikz image vertically.

The code that I am using for the figure:

```latex
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to[short, o-] ++(-1, 0) to[american voltage source=\( V \), i=\( i \)] ++(0, 3) to[short, -o] ++(1, 0);
    \end{circuitikz}
    \hskip 25pt
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xlabel=\( i \), ylabel=\( V \), xmin=0, xmax=10, ymin=0, ymax=1.5, ticks=none, axis lines=middle, scale=0.6]
            \addplot[domain=0:10, samples=100, color=red]{1};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{\centering Ideal constant voltage source}
\end{figure}
```

This gives the following output:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `tabular` with `m` columns can help:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{m{2cm}m{4cm}}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to[short, o-] ++(-1, 0) to[american voltage source=\( V \), i=\( i \)] ++(0, 3) to[short, -o] ++(1, 0);
   \end{circuitikz}
&
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xlabel=\( i \), ylabel=\( V \), xmin=0, xmax=10, ymin=0, ymax=1.5, ticks=none, axis lines=middle, scale=0.6]
            \addplot[domain=0:10, samples=100, color=red]{1};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
    \caption{\centering Ideal constant voltage source}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly!

Comment: Two minipages alongside would do prety much the same too.

Answer (score 0):

Although [@Ignasi answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/600938/38080) is clear the Right One here, let me show you how to align the pictures on a general point. In the case below, I named the generator `V_p` and put the same value in the diagram.

Now I have two nodes, one which is the voltage label of the `circuitikz` symbol (you can see [in the manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/circuitikz/0#subsection.5.6) that it will be called `Vpvoltage`) and the one defined in the graph. By setting the baseline of the whole picture on the baseline of such nodes, we will obtain to line them up.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{circuitikz}[baseline=(Vpvoltage.base)]
        \draw (0,0) to[short, o-] ++(-1, 0) 
             to[american voltage source=$V_p$, i=$i$, name=Vp] ++(0, 3) 
             to[short, -o] ++(1, 0);
   \end{circuitikz}
\qquad
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(Vpgraph.base)]
        \begin{axis}[xlabel=$i$, ylabel=$V$, xmin=0, xmax=10, ymin=0, ymax=1.5, 
                    ticks=none, axis lines=middle, scale=0.6, clip mode=individual]
            \addplot[domain=0:10, samples=100, color=red]{1};
            \node[left](Vpgraph) at (0,1) {$V_p$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \caption{\centering Ideal constant voltage source}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]